# How to use recipes package to replace missing values with a constant

Tags: r, missing-data, r-recipes

I can't figure out how to use the recipes package to replace missing numeric variables with a constant.

I did think about using step_lowerimpute, but I don't think I will be able to use it for my case. step_lowerimpute replaces missing values **below** a given threshold with random numbers between **0** and the threshold. In my case that will not work.

For example, I have some lab variable, like lactic acid, which is often missing. I want to replace missing values with an extreme value, such as -9999.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show what you tried and describe how it didn't do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This is my first day looking at the recipes package (so perhaps not the most reliable answer ...).  I had the same question and believe that the following works as required:

```
rec <-
    recipe( ~ ., data = airquality) %>%
    step_mutate(
        Ozone = tidyr::replace_na(Ozone, -9999)
    ) %>%
    prep(training = airquality, retain = TRUE)

juice(rec)
```

Before coming across this method, I also tried creating my own step, which also seems to work, but above is much simpler  ...

```
step_nareplace <- 
    function(recipe, 
            ..., 
            role = NA, 
            trained = FALSE,  
            skip = FALSE,
            columns = NULL,
            replace = -9,
            id = rand_id("nareplace")) {
  add_step(
    recipe,
    step_nareplace_new(
      terms = ellipse_check(...),
      role = role,
      trained = trained,
      skip = skip,
      id = id,
      replace = replace,
      columns = columns
    )
  )
}

step_nareplace_new <- 
    function(terms, role, trained, skip, id, columns, replace) {
  step(
    subclass = "nareplace",
    terms = terms,
    role = role,
    trained = trained,
    skip = skip,
    id = id,
    columns = columns,
    replace = replace
  )
}

prep.step_nareplace <- function(x, training, info = NULL, ...) {

    col_names <- terms_select(x$terms, info = info)

    step_nareplace_new(
        terms = x$terms,
        role = x$role,
        trained = TRUE,
        skip = x$skip,
        id = x$id,
        columns = col_names,
        replace = x$replace
      )
}

bake.step_nareplace <- function(object, new_data, ...) {
  for (i in  object$columns) {
    if (any(is.na(new_data[, i])))
      new_data[is.na(new_data[, i]), i] <- object$replace
  }
  as_tibble(new_data)
}

print.step_nareplace <-
  function(x, width = max(20, options()$width - 30), ...) {
    cat("Replacing NA values in ", sep = "")
    cat(format_selectors(x$terms, wdth = width))
    cat("\n")
    invisible(x)
  }

tidy.step_nareplace <- function(x, ...) {
  res <- simple_terms(x, ...)
  res$id <- x$id
  res
}


recipe(Ozone ~ ., data = airquality) %>%
   step_nareplace(Ozone, replace = -9999) %>%
   prep(airquality, verbose = FALSE, retain = TRUE) %>%
   juice()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `step_unknown()` function, which replaces missing values `NA` values with a `new_level` that the user can provide.

Comment: `step_unknown` only works for factors and chars. `step_mutate` and `step_mutate_at` is probably relevant. https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_mutate_at.html?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you specifically need the recipes package to do this? Just replacing all NAs with a constant value can be done quite easy.

```
library(imputeTS)
na.replace(yourDataframe, fill = -9999)
```

Other solution (without additional package):

```
yourDataframe[is.na(yourDataframe)] <- -9999
```

Comment: Thanks @stats0007! 

The recipes package has the capability to automatically determine the types of all the variables in the input data set. I want to apply this to all the numeric variables at once, and I think the recipes packaged is probably faster than doing it "by hand." I may have to end up doing that if I can't find a way in recipes.